# CCScrollView Detecting Paging iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccscrollview

I'm using `CCScrollView` to create a paging level select screen that is popular in many puzzle games. However, I would like to be able to detect when paging occurs. Right now, my code creates a paging view exactly as I want it to, however, I am not able to detect changes.

I know that in order to do that, I must use `CCScrollViewDelegate`. It seems that as soon as I make it a delegate I lose the snap paging that I want (i.e. it becomes a constant scroll.)

I'll happily upload any code anybody would like to see. I set up everything that is suggested [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/73487/spritebuilder-and-ccscrollview-page-indicators-not-showing-up). Except instead of using `didLoadFromCCB`, I used `onEnter` (since I'm not using any CCBs)

The onEnter code, ideally setting up the delegate and the property.

```
- (void) onEnter {

_groupSelect.delegate = self;
self.pagingEnabled = true;

}
```

Code that should log out the page number, which it successfully does, but on a continuous scroll, not a paging.

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(CCScrollView *)scrollView {

NSLog(@"%i", self.groupSelect.horizontalPage);

}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of what you tried?

Comment: Can you add some code of the content of the CCScrollView?

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the delegate methods of `CCScrollView`, for example:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(TBRCarousel *)scrollView
{
    int currentPage = scrollView.horizontalPage;
}
```

Also make sure you set the `pagingEnabled` property to `YES`

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL pagingEnabled;
```

Comment: `@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL pagingEnabled;`

I'll give this a try, the other methods I was using to set `pagingEnabled` didn't seem to want to be working.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and my paging is still disabled for whatever reason. I uploaded some of the code. I'm mostly self taught, so I might just be totally missing something simple to do with delegates :/